# In Google Analytics: How to combain data from several subdomains in one report?

Tags: google-analytics

My need is to combine the same type of data (Behaviour/Content drilldown) from two different subdomains on my site. (For instance Unique page views, etc.) The main site is https://www.nacka.se and I need two combine to subdomains like https://www.nacka.se/xxxxxx and https://www.nacka.se/yyyyy so the data can be seen in the same report, and then exported to .pdf.

But I simply cannot find out how to do this. I guess that this must be done through "custom reports". I have been informed that it should be possible in some way through using "the common denominator" in the URL (www.nacka.se), but how?

Most thankful for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*FYI what you're referring to is called a subfolder, a subdomain would be something like https://somethingelse.nacka.se/*

To add to DalmTo's answer:

**If different properties/tracking IDs (UA-XXXXXXX-X) were used**

- `Google Data Studio`: [that's probably the easiest way to create reports from multiple properties](https://datastudio.google.com/). Just create 1 data source for each property and that's it.
- `Google Sheets with GA API add-on`: [if you prefer working with spreadsheets](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/google-analytics-spreadsheet-add-on).
- `GA 360 (formerly GA Premium)`: it has a [roll-up feature for cross-property reporting](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6096167?hl=en), but you have to pay several `$K` a months for 360

**If you used the same property/tracking ID**

- `Google Analytics reporting UI`: go to `Reports -> Behavior -> Site Content - Content Drilldown` and you'll see a breakdown of top-level folders
- `Google Analytics API`: you can still use Data Studio or Google Sheets options listed above or build your own solution

For all above options, the GA dimension you're looking for is called [`ga:pagePathLevel1`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=page_tracking&jump=ga_pagepathlevel1) in the API, and `Page path level 1` in the in the reporting interface.

Comment: Thanks for the correction regarding subfolders! I will check all your suggestions later, I just learned that there are some more details concerning the organisation of our site that I must learn before I can go on with the actual problem. So for now, I just say Thank You, I will try to come back when I am better prepared.

Comment: I have not forgot it! But I am not sure that I have understood it! Anyway, my manager seemed to like your answer, she wanted to see it and did find it useful, and therefore I will of course accept the answer! =)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the data is being insert into different properties on Google analytics website then the simple answer is you cant.   There is no way to analyse data between websites in the Google Analytics website.

You could attempt to use the Google Analytics API to extract some data out for each of the websites and analyze this data locally although I would personally question how useful any results you would get for comparing different websites would be.

Comment: Thank you for quick answer! I will check all your suggestions later, I just learned that there are some more details concerning the organisation of our site that I must learn before I can go on with the actual problem. So for now, I just say Thank You, I will try to come back when I am better prepared.